# JqueryMobile issue when working with Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I found jquery mobile is not rendering correctly when the element is generated by knockoutjs (or probably not rendering correctly when element is generated dynamically). See the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/wRRZk/1/

**updates**:

One solution is to load jquery-mobile js file after KO binding finished as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/wRRZk/3/, however this doesn't solve the problem that jquerymobile render fail when changing KO model dynamically, as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/wRRZk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to tell jQueryMobile to create those elements into the jQM enhanced version using the API. Check here :: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html and look halfway down for "Enhancing new markup" and the section just below.

As for the create/refresh ... might need to be somewhat judicious in know when and where you're adding new stuff, and whether a create or refresh is needed.

I've done a new version of the jsFiddle here :: http://jsfiddle.net/wRRZk/5/.
I'm also removing from the model afterwards, which does seem to remove the links too, BUT, I *think* that may also be because the jQM enhancement is keeping the same anchor, thus the reference knockout as is still valid.

Not too sure how well that will work for the other enhancements done by jQM.